# Strange rendering issue in Chrome with floats in a div with margin-top

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-float

The following html renders differently in Chrome and Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       .outer {
         margin-top: 10px;
         clear: both;
       }
       .inner {
         float: left;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"> Inner1 </div>
      <div class="inner"> Inner2 </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox (and IE10), Inner1 and Inner2 line up vertically. In Chrome, Inner2 is 10px down from Inner1. What's going on?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8wLT/

My Chrome is version 25.0.1364.172 m
My Firefox is version 19.0.2

**Edit:** In the actual (not simplified) version of this problem, I've worked around it using `display: inline-block`s instead of `float: left`s, I just thought it was curious, and hope to learn why it renders differently, and which rendering is correct. I'm assuming Chrome is getting it wrong, but maybe not.

Comment: try clear: right; in .inner{

Comment: `clear: right;` in `.inner` doesn't change anything...

Comment: see the answer below!

Comment: delete clear:both; in .outer

Comment: Looks like a rendering bug in Chrome to me. Once I look at the CSS rules via inspect element, then disable the float property for `.inner` elements and then enable it again, the effect is gone and both are on the same level.

Comment: @KeesSonnema, ah, ok. What if there are multiple `.outer` divs, and I want them below each other: http://jsfiddle.net/d9mS2/

Answer (score 1):

Simply add overflow: hidden to the outer DIV which will allow outer to expand its height to accommodate it's floating children.

```
.outer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8wLT/1/

Comment: also, adding `height: 1px` (or any non-zero height) to `.outer` makes it appear as expected.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with the tried and tested method I've suggested as stating 1px height may produce unexpected results in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem delete

```
clear: both;
```

in your .outer div.

if you want to have more outer div beneath eachother
just put a `<br>` between them.

http://jsfiddle.net/d9mS2/3/